# How to post form serialize data using PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, form-serialize

I have a form that contain dynamically generated fields. I need to post the form using .serialize().

**Ajax**

```
$("#save").click(function () {                              
    formData = $('#myForm').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",         
        url: base_url +'home/save',
        data: {
            formData:formData,
            csrf_test_name: csrf_token
        },
        success: function(response){         
            console.log(response);           
            alert(response);
        }     
    }); 
});
```

I need to post all the data using input field name. Now I got all the result like that:

```
   echo $fomdata=$this->input->post('formData');
```

**output**

`room_count_new=5&room_id=1&bedcount_1_1=1&extra_age_1_1_1=middle&extra_age_1_1_2=0&bedcount_1_2=0`

But I want to post with the corresponding name.

Comment: With jQuery `$.ajax` you can send `data` like this: `data: { var1:val1, var2:val2, var3:val3 ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the object with `formdata` property and only send the serialized string and add the `csrf` to the end of it or add the csrf to the form as a hidden input and let it get serialized also in `serialize()`

```
$("#save").click(function() {
  var formData = $('#myForm').serialize();
  formData += '&csrf_test_name=' + csrf_token

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: base_url + 'home/save',
    data: formData,
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      alert(response)
    }
  });
});
```

Then in php access the same names as in form.

```
$fomdata=$this->input->post();

$roomCount = $fomdata['room_count_new'];
$csrfToken = $fomdata['csrf_test_name'];
```

Comment: how to post data using the corresponding field name

Comment: we can post only using the name formData

Comment: Updated using your `$formData` array. This is exact same as if you submitted the form without ajax

Comment: i got the result..can u please tell me how to post like $this->input->post()

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. I showed how to use `$this->input->post()` at bottom of answer

Comment: Any relevence for this variable formData?

Comment: No...can name variables any way you want. I just used your naming convention